# What should be the best way to filter the kafka message

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm consuming data from a kafka topic which includes the area code. I have to filter the data only for certain area codes. Can any one suggest be the best approach to solve this.

Here is my listener code looks like. Is it best practice to parse the data into object(as I mapped the payload to a TEST object) and filter the data based on the value which I need to filter or Does kafka provides any other libraries which I can make use of this filtering process.

**Kafka Listener Method**

```
@Service
public class Listener{

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{@topicName}")
        public void listen(String payload) throws IOException {

            LOGGER.info("received payload from topic='{}'", payload);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

            TEST test = objectMapper.readValue(payload,TEST.class);

        }
}
```

My Kafka Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, applicationConfiguration.getKafkaBootStrap());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, applicationConfiguration.getKafkaKeyDeserializer());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, applicationConfiguration.getKafkaValueDeserializer());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, applicationConfiguration.getKafkaGroupId());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, applicationConfiguration.getKafkaAutoOffsetReset());
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public Listener receiver() {
        return new Listener();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Filtering Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#filtering-messages).

> The Spring for Apache Kafka project also provides some assistance by means of the FilteringMessageListenerAdapter class, which can wrap your MessageListener. This class takes an implementation of RecordFilterStrategy in which you implement the filter method to signal that a message is a duplicate and should be discarded. This has an additional property called ackDiscarded, which indicates whether the adapter should acknowledge the discarded record. It is false by default.
>
> When you use `@KafkaListener`, set the `RecordFilterStrategy` (and optionally ackDiscarded) on the container factory so that the listener is wrapped in the appropriate filtering adapter.

```
/**
 * Set the record filter strategy.
 * @param recordFilterStrategy the strategy.
 */
public void setRecordFilterStrategy(RecordFilterStrategy<? super K, ? super V> recordFilterStrategy) {
    this.recordFilterStrategy = recordFilterStrategy;
}
```

```java
/**
 * Implementations of this interface can signal that a record about
 * to be delivered to a message listener should be discarded instead
 * of being delivered.
 *
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 *
 */
public interface RecordFilterStrategy<K, V> {

    /**
     * Return true if the record should be discarded.
     * @param consumerRecord the record.
     * @return true to discard.
     */
    boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<K, V> consumerRecord);

}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, i came across this answer while searching for some similar solution, may i know if there's significant efficiency difference if I implement `RecordFilterStrategy` or if i filter based on the message header in the `@KafkaListener` receive method?

Comment: I would not expect any significant difference; it's just a mechanism that allows separation of concerns (filtering Vs. business logic).

Comment: Does RecordFilterStrategy execute after deserialization or before ? as it is taking consumerRecord as input. I'm assuming after deserialization

Comment: Yes after. Spring only gets the CR. You could use a custom deserializer to return null instead of deserializing, then filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is alright.
If your payload has a lot of data besides the area code and you worry about long parsing, you can filter the messages before doing the whole parsing to TEST object by adding the area code as a header.

Later versions of Kafka (after 0.11) offers custom [headers](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers.html) ([KIP-82](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers))

If you want to implement it by yourself (or if you use older version of Kafka), you can add the header to your message payload, lets say as the first 4 bytes of the message, they will represent the area code and can be extracted very fast prior to the parsing process.
New message payload:

```
([header-4-bytes],[original-payload-n-bytes])
```

So make your filter based on the header, and if you find out this is an area code you need, create your TEST object based on the rest of the message (cut the first 4 bytes to remove the header).

Kafka does not provide any filtering options that could help you, though it has the ability to send keyed messages in your Producer, so if your key is the area code Kafka guarantees that all messages with the same area codes goes to the same parition, maybe can help for your performance if used correctly.
The Producer can also send messages to a specific partitions, so if you knew you have fixed area code numbers you could also define the topic with partition number equal to the unique area codes count and send each area code to different partition, then use your Consumer to access only to the partitions with the area codes you are looking for, but, may be overkill for most cases.